# what to do to make all the leaves of my Nerium variegata turn yellow?

Tags: plant-care, leaves, pruning

I live in Portugal. I have a neriun oleander variegata whose leaves are on certain branches completely yellow.
How can I get the whole bush to give leaves whid this color?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - it's just a genetic thing. The genetic programming for each branch and leaf may have minor variations, so some will be highly variegated, others less so and some may be yellow or even plain green. That's assuming the plant is healthy and growing well - if it's not, the yellow leaves may be about to shrivel and drop off.

Comment: but what if I use the branches with yellow leaves, to make stakes, then would I be transmitting only genes with a yellow character, or does it not work like that?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Not necessarily,, and anyway, all yellow or white leaves on variegated plants don't have much or any chlorophyll and make for weak plants, but you can try it if you want. Better from cuttings though, instructions here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/shrubs/oleander/rooting-oleander-cuttings.htm